# Showing Homogeneity of norm $||(x,y)||=\sup_{0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi} || x \cos\theta + y\sin\theta ||$

Tags: normed-spaces

I am starting with a normed space $X$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with norm $||\cdot||_X$.

I have to prove that the following is a norm on $X\times X$ over $\mathbb{C}$:
$$||(x,y)||=\sup_{0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi} || x \cos\theta + y\sin\theta ||_X$$
and with addition and scalar multiplication defined by:
$$ (x,y)+(x_1, y_1)=(x+x_1,y+y_1) $$
$$ (a+ib)(x,y)=(ax-by, bx+ay) $$
I have already shown triangle inequality, and the fact that $||(x,y)||=0 \iff (x,y)=(0,0)$.  But I am stuck on homogeneity, ie

> Show that for any $(x,y)\in X\times X$ and $a+ib \in \mathbb{C}$, we have
>   $$ || (a+ib)(x,y) || = |a+ib| \cdot ||(x,y)|| $$

My issue is that I can start off easily by following definitions,
$$||(a+ib)(x,y)||=\sup_{0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi} ||(ax-by)\cos\theta + (bx+ay)\sin\theta ||_X $$
but I **cannot** for the life of me make this look like how I want, which is
$$ \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \,\, ||(x,y)|| $$
I'm not sure how to introduce the square root and squares..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a trap to go the direct route. Note that, clearly, if $r\geq 0,$ then
$$
\| (rx,ry)\|=r\|(x,y)\|
$$
Hence, let $\varphi\in \mathbb{R}$ and consider

\begin{align}
\| e^{i\varphi}(x,y)\| &=\sup_{\theta} \|(\cos(\varphi)x-\sin(\varphi)y)\cos(\theta)+(\sin(\varphi)x+\cos(\varphi)y)\sin(\theta)\|_X \\
&= \sup_{\theta} \| x (\cos(\varphi)\cos(\theta)+\sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta))+y(\cos(\varphi)\sin(\theta)-\sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta))\|_X \\
&=\sup_{\theta} \| x(\cos(\varphi+\theta+\pi))-y(\sin(\varphi+\theta+\pi))\|_X \\
&= \sup_{\theta} \| x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)\|_X\\
&= \|(x,y)\|
\end{align}

Hence,
$$
\| re^{i\theta}(x,y)\|=r\| e^{i\theta}(x,y)\|=r\|(x,y)\|,
$$
which is what we wanted.

Comment: Originally tried this too, but the trig identities is where I got terminated... thanks!

Comment: Yeah... the sign is chosen in an odd way. The computation would probably look more natural if you let $i$ act as $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ instead of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.